# Best way to model resource ownership

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

Lets say I have a number of (less than fifty) entities in my datamodel and I need to store who owns this entity for security reasons. I need to be able to decide on each request if the user doing a specific action on a resource is allowed to do that (who is doing what on which resource). And for this the resource ownership is needed.

I can think of several different ways to do this. One is that in each table I can have a foreing key pointing to the owner. One downside with this solution is that in code I need to look at each individual table to find out the ownership. Each time there is a new table added I would need to update the code to look in that new table.

Another solution could be to treat every specific entity as a generic resource, a resource that has an ownership. And store that ownership in one single table. I could even do that without any foreign key relationship and deal with it in code to keep the resource table in sync and e.g. make sure that each new entry in any table has a corresponding record in the "resource" table. One obvious downside would be that there will be a lot of records in this table. The benefit would be that there is one single place to go to to find the ownership.

So what would be the preferred way? Would there be a performance problem with storing the ownership in one table, given there might be in the range of hundreds of thousands of records (possibly even millions) in it eventually? What about the cost of preserving lots of foreign key constraints? Is there a better way of solving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're working in an object oriented language. Inheritance is perfect to solve this problem.

Depending on if you use Code First, or DB First, your approach will be slightly different, but boils down to this:

1. Make and abstract class, you can call it something like 'OwnableEntity'. In essence, you put your foreign key and navigation property in there.
2. Inherit all your entities from this 'OwnableEntity'
3. Make sure that your inheritance mapping in EF is correct (in this case, [TPC inheritance](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) mapping is what you will probably want to use)

From now on, you can write your 'check ownership' logic against 'OwnableEntity', and it will be OK for every entity you implement later on.

Comment: Sounds good. If I understand TPC correctly this would result in (assuming the ownership class is abstract) each concrete type table to keep two columns that would be the same in every other concrete class. One reference to the owner and one OwnableEntity-key column . So the ownership details would not be stored in a separate table but spread out in each concrete subtype table. Is it somehow enforced that not two concrete type records in differrent tables share the same OwnableEntity-key?